# Need a way to check which geometry points are within a set distance from each other at a given time interval

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, spatial

So i have a spatial database with ship coordinates named "ships". 
It has the following tables:

```
SHIPS
============
id (serial)
vessel(uuid)
time(timestamp without timezone)
coord(geometry(Point, 4326)
```

I need to write a query that returns vessels that  their coordinates are X meters far, with a Y time interval. So far i have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.vessel, b.vessel) a.vessel, b.vessel 
FROM ships a
INNER JOIN ships b
ON a.vessel = b.vessel
WHERE
ST_DWithin((ST_Transform(a.coord, 3035)),(ST_Transform(b.coord, 3035)), 5000)
AND (EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM(a.time - b.time))) <= 1500
AND (a.vessel != b.vessel);
```

but it always returns null if i leave the a.vessel != b.vessel constraint, and if i delete it the results are the same vessel on both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong condition in the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.vessel, b.vessel) a.vessel, b.vessel 
FROM ships a
INNER JOIN ships b
ON ST_DWithin((ST_Transform(a.coord, 3035)),(ST_Transform(b.coord, 3035)), 5000)
WHERE
(EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM(a.time - b.time))) <= 1500
AND (a.vessel != b.vessel);
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate. 
Ive been running the query for the last 30 minutes on 500.000 rows and it still hasnt finished. Is it normal?

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on `ships(ST_Transform(coord,3035))`?

Comment: I didnt.
i just used "CREATE INDEX coord_gix ON ships USING GIST (coord);" to make one and run the query again. Is that the right way?

Comment: Did you check what `EXPLAIN` has to say about your query? Does it use the index? You probably need an index of the form `CREATE INDEX coord_gix ON ships USING GIST (ST_Transform(coord,3035));`. Create it and then check with `EXPLAIN` if it is being used.

Comment: i just run it and theres nothing on the "explain" tab. Is it supposed to print something there the moment you run it?

Comment: ok the query plan says it uses the index so ill run the SELECT again and wait to see. Thanks a lot for the help mate

Comment: 30 minutes later still hasnt finished, this time on 300.000 rows

Comment: @OdysseasVangelis IIf it's taking too long to complete, there might be an issue with the `ST_DWithin((ST_Transform(a.coord, 3035)),(ST_Transform(b.coord, 3035)), 5000)` expression. I don't have a postgis installation to test it right now. You should post a separate question on gis.stackexchange.com.